# Settings window doesn't show up on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: gnome, settings

I have a problem with Settings window not showing up when I open it on my laptop.

Whenever I start the application, even from Terminal with command `gnome-control-center`, I can see the Settings icon showing up in the sidebar, but no window appearing on my screen.
I see something starts appearing on the right side of the screen, but it disappears almost immediately.

If I right click on the sidebar icon, and select *All Windows*, I can see the window preview, but even if I click on it, nothing happens.
I have already tried to see if it is inside a different work area, and also to open it in a new area - same behaviour.

I'm running Ubuntu on my laptop, no additional display present.
I'm attaching a screenshot of the Settings icon on the side bar, and the response from `gnome-control-center -v` command.

[image: settings icon]

[image: terminal diagnostic]

Any idea how to fix that? I hope you could help me as I'm pretty new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the cause of the settings app disappearing but I did find a solution that worked here https://trendoceans.com/how-to-fix-missing-settings-in-ubuntu-20-10-in-a-gnome-environment/

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

Answer (score 2):

If your laptop has two displays, just go to 'Settings > Displays' and select 'Single Display'.

To show the settings window for the first time:

1. Make it active by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. Maximize it by <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>.
3. Drag it out from the left of the screen (or the right, wherever you see it blinks when you open it). <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> Or <kbd>Right</kbd> might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable/remove all other workplaces except the current one and try again, if doesnt work or if the instance create a new workspace itself, then
2. Remove and reinstall gnome-control-center using `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-control-center` and then install using `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`
3. Reboot system

Caution:  You may lose the trivial gnome settings you already applied.

Comment: Thank you aneesh_nair.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
Uninstall and new installation went fine, however, after reboot. the behaviour is just the same.
I can confirm that there is no additional active workspace.

Thanks for your time, in any case,

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem solved by updating my drivers through following command:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

which selects recommended drivers for you.

OH, don't forget to **restart**!

Answer (score 1):

Give a try by reinstalling gnome-control-center, it worked in my scenario.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the issue.

It was due to graphic card open source drivers (X.Org server Nouveau display driver) being used.
I have switched to Nvidia 390 proprietary driver, and now I can display the Settings.

Should anybody be interested in gpu details (Nvidia GT540M) in order to fix the issue with the free driver, just let me know, and I'll send it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by selecting window from left side (sidebar) as the way you have said then pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on my keyboard, then pressed <kbd>↓</kbd> three times and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (move window is selected, you can test it on any window), then pressed <kbd>←</kbd> until I see the window appearing from right-side.